# Вывести самое большое и самое маленькое число из массива

Tags: php

Вывожу массив из: `$room_type = $room->room_prices;`

Массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1500
            [color] => #8224e3
            [row_type] => Партер
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1300
            [color] => #1e73be
            [row_type] => Партер
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1200
            [color] => #81d742
            [row_type] => Партер
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1200
            [color] => #eeee22
            [row_type] => Амфитеатр
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1100
            [color] => #dd9933
            [row_type] => Амфитеатр
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [price] => 1000
            [color] => #dd3333
            [row_type] => Амфитеатр
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [price] => 800
            [color] => #37aab2
            [row_type] => Амфитеатр
        )

)
```

Как из этого массива вывести самое маленькое и самое большое число, которое находится в `[price]`

Comment: `$max = max(array_column($array, 'price')); $min = min(array_column($array, 'price'));`

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось!